# Int object is not subscriptable, but it is a list

Tags: python

I am trying to write some code for a chess application. One line of code in a function is:

```
if check_mate(board, True) == True:
    value = 999
```

the checkmate function is:

```
def check_mate(board, previous):
    if previous != True:
        prev = previous
    elif previous == True:
        if len(move_history_int) != 0:
            prev = move_history_int[-1]
        else:
            prev = [0,0,0,0]
```

the length of move_history_int is 0, so prev becomes `[0,0,0,0]`, but later on in check_mate, it gives me the error

```
if prev[-1][0] == element - 1 and  prev[-1][1] == z and prev[-1][2] == element - 1 and prev[-1][3] == row:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Doing `print(prev)` gives `[0,0,0,0]` and trying `print(type(prev))` gives list. I can't think of what is going wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `print(prev[-1])` show you? Does that help to understand the issue?

Comment: If `prev` is `[0,0,0,0]`, what do you imagine `prev[-1][0]` would give you?

Comment: If `prev` is `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, `prev[-1]` is `0`, so you can't use `prev[-1][0]` because that's the same as `0[0]`.

Comment: `prev[-1][0]` only works if `prev` is 2-dimensional.

Comment: This question is not really answerable without knowing the context surrounding move_history_int and prev. If you include where they are defined and modified it would be much easier to give an answer.

Comment: @hifkanotiks That's irrelevant, he says this happens after it goes into the `else: prev = [0, 0, 0, 0]` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if prev[-1][0] == element - 1 and  prev[-1][1] == z and prev[-1][2] == element - 1 and prev[-1][3] == row:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

This error is telling you that **previous** can't be double-subscripted. That's because you're using a one-dimensional list, as we see in:

```
prev = [0,0,0,0]
```

Because it's a one-dimensional list, calling prev[-1][0] attempts to call the first list item of the list at prev[-1]...but prev[-1] isn't itself a list, as if you do:

```
>>> prev = [0,0,0,0]
>>> prev[-1]
0
>>> type(prev[-1])
>>> <type 'int'>
```

So, to fix this, figure out what you're trying to extract from your one-dimensional list, or refactor your list to be a two-dimensional list.